# Binary Logistic: p value of categorical variable vs. p value for each - overall or individual p-value?

Tags: logistic, p-value, binary-data

I am running Binary logistic regression to see the impact of religion, ethnicity, educational background and other few factors on high frequency of time spent together in marriage.

In the outputs, I'm confused to see the overall p-value of religion is significant, however, the p-value for each religion is not (for all religion).  How should I understand this?  Please help.  Thanks a lot in advance.

In the photo, D7A is the variable for religion
[image]

Comment: Could be the interaction effect of all the religions taken at the same time

Comment: I wonder what’s the sample size and if you have put too many variables in your model

Comment: Could you clarify what these variables are? You’ve given us a table of uninformative variable names so it’s a little hard to understand what’s going on. For example, what are he different D7A options? What is the excluded group?